# tsc in an ASP.NET Core and Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, tsc

I am working on a new project using `.NET Core rc2` WebAPI and `Angular2 rc1` using `TypeScript`. Everything is setup and working well. `.NET Core` only handles the API and `Angular2` handles all views.

My `ts` files are in a sub-folder `script` of the root project folder because they need access to the `node_modules` folder. In my `tsconfig` I have an `outDir` which points to `wwwroot/app`. My `ts` files are compiled into that folder, which then contains the `js` and the `js.map` files. However, they do not contain the `ts` files themselves and as a result I cannot debug them in chrome or firebug.

Moving everything to the `wwwroot/app` folder is not a solution as I would then also need to move `node_modules` to `wwwroot` which would result in a huge publish package.

I definitely want to run `tsc` in watch mode with `node.js`'s `lite-server` in watch mode as well. This setup speeds up development significantly and I don't want to miss that option.

I think what I need is a way to compile everything in my `root/script` folder (the `map` files need to point to the correct location of the `ts` files) and then as a post-build process copy everything (`ts, js and js.map`) into the `wwwroot/app` folder.

Is it possible to run `tsc` in watch mode with such a post build task that fires whenever one or more `ts` files are compiled?

Any other solutions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compile your Typescript using a node module and then create a watch task to check for updates in your files, using Grunt (grunt-typescrpit) or Gulp.

E.g: [Automating TypeScript with Node And Grunt](http://jessefreeman.com/dev-techniques/automating-typescript-with-node-and-grunt/)